# Spring test-mvc PUT not supported

Tags: spring, spring-test-mvc

This is my Controller method:

```java
    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.PUT,produces="application/json", headers = "content-type=application/json")
    public @ResponseBody User updateUser(@RequestBody User user) throws PropertyErrorException, ItemNotFoundException {         
        return service.UpdateUser(user);     
    }
```

Using Spring test-mvc I would like to write a unit test case:

```java
@Test
public void UpdateUser() throws Exception {     
    mockMvc.perform(put("/r01/users").body(userJsonString.getBytes())
        .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
        .andExpect(status().isOk())
        .andExpect(content().type(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
        .andExpect(content().string(userString));
}
```

Running this test case generates:

```java
WARN org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound - Request method 'PUT' not supported
```

Also, updateUser method is never called and the response code is 405.

I have written a lot of tests, all GET requests, and they are working correctly. This means that I am confident in ContextConfiguration. What have I missed?

Comment: after one year. having the same issue here. did you mange to do put request? thanks in advance, oak

Comment: ok i got it i was converting to json also getters with no setter. and there for the request was been rejected. my solution for this is  skip those kind of getters. i.e :`ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
mapper.configure(MapperFeature.REQUIRE_SETTERS_FOR_GETTERS, true);
 return mapper.writeValueAsBytes(object);`

Answer (score 3):

You are explicitly expecting a header of content-type in your @RequestMapping method but not sending the content type in your request, I think that is the reason why the request is failing..try this.

```
mockMvc.perform(put("/r01/users").contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).body(userJsonString.getBytes())
    .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
    .andExpect(status().isOk())
    .andExpect(content().type(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
    .andExpect(content().string(userString));
```

Comment: I'v tried with "contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)" no difference.

Comment: Just to try out something different, if you remove `headers = "content-type=application/json"` does it still not work?

Comment: Hi. I have tried that to, and a lot of permutations around that thema.